# Require local ip to access an Apache served site hosted externally

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

Attempting to configure Apache 2.4 access control: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html

I have a site hosted on an external machine, serving from Apache 2.4. I need to restrict access to the site to only those machines on the local (company) network.

This is very nearly a duplicate of a question found on the webmasters exchange: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59624/allowing-access-to-an-apache-virtual-host-from-the-local-network-only

The company machines are set up on a private network (ie. 10.0.0.100 type IP address). My impression is that requiring an ip that begins with 10. would not allow access because the machine is outside the network.

What IP pattern would be consistent across machines on the local network?

Comment: By "external machine", do you mean one that is detached from your internal network, and only reachable over the internet?

Comment: @guzzijason yes, exactly. Only reachable over the internet. It is an ubuntu vm facilitated through Azure.

Comment: OK, keep in mind that 10.X.X.X addresses **do not** route across the internet (refer to [RFC 11918](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918). If your internal hosts are able to access external sites, they must be doing it via a NAT translation. You need to determine the public NAT address, and then use that in your apache access rules. From one of your internal hosts, you can try this curl to try and determine the public IP they are using: `curl ipinfo.io/ip`